# SQL Server connection related error

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, connection-string

Below error is thrown in a already opened program which connects to different database

> A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Program details: code done using vb.net with SQL Server 2008 as back-end

Two instance of same exe where running simultaneously in same PC but error was thrown only by one instance

Program uses both `SqlConnection` (ADO.NET) and `ADODB` connection (upgraded from VB6) and the error is thrown by both types of connection

If the error is due to network problem with the server then why few programs work fine? I am not able to trace the reason for this behavior of the program

Can I know why this error occurs and why only in few programs of same instance

Answer (score 0):

When each instance of your exe connects, it gets its own SQL Server process ID (SPID). You are getting the error because your instance's connection was either killed at the server level or disrupted at the network level, at some point before it tried to execute the SQL command where the error occurred.

In SSMS, check your SQL Server Log file. In this example I killed a SPID, and the killing of the SPID was logged:
[image]

If you don't see a logged event, you are probably dealing with a network issue. Further troubleshooting might involve setting one or more break points in your code somewhere after it opens the ADODB connection, but before the error, and then verifying through SSMS that a SPID for that instance is running at the break point. `exec sp_who2` is a good command to list all currently active SPIDs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Form2



Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Function call_add()

    Dim tam, eng, mat, sci, soc, tot As Decimal
    tam = 0
    eng = 0
    mat = 0
    sci = 0
    soc = 0
    tot = 0
    If tamil.Text <> "" Then
        tam = Convert.ToDecimal(tamil.Text)
    End If
    If english.Text <> "" Then
        eng = Convert.ToDecimal(english.Text)
    End If

    If maths.Text <> "" Then
        mat = Convert.ToDecimal(maths.Text)
    End If

    If science.Text <> "" Then
        sci = Convert.ToDecimal(science.Text)
    End If

    If social.Text <> "" Then
        soc = Convert.ToDecimal(social.Text)
    End If

    tot = tam + eng + mat + sci + soc
    total.Text = tot.ToString
    percentage.Text = total.Text / 500 * 100

    Return False
End Function

Private Sub total_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles total.TextChanged
    call_add()
End Sub

Private Sub percentage_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles percentage.TextChanged
    call_add()

End Sub

Private Sub tamil_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tamil.TextChanged
    call_add()

End Sub

Private Sub english_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles english.TextChanged
    call_add()

End Sub

Private Sub maths_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles maths.TextChanged
    call_add()

End Sub

Private Sub science_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles science.TextChanged
    call_add()

End Sub

Private Sub social_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles social.TextChanged
    call_add()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    'Dim str As String
    con = New SqlConnection("server=WHITE-PC\WHITEPC;initial catalog=markreg;Integrated Security=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    con.Open()
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    command = New SqlCommand("stdregno,stdname,tamil,english,maths,science,social,total,percentage", con)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Added Sucessfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Succesfully")
    call_clear()
End Sub
Private Function call_clear()

    stdregno.Text = ""
    stdname.Text = ""
    tamil.Text = ""
    english.Text = ""
    maths.Text = ""
    science.Text = ""
    social.Text = ""
    total.Text = ""
    percentage.Text = ""
End Function


Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    InputBox("Enter the Regno You want search")

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    InputBox("Enter the Regno You want Modify")
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and format code properly.